# Github color theme

Tags: themes

I just noticed that Github did something to code highlighting theme they are using, and for whatever reason, it looks very compelling to me. Is there already an Emacs version of this theme? Is there an easy way of converting the CSS file somehow?

Comment: Unlikely, especially if they keep changing the theme. Same goes for conversion, the easiest way is paying someone to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may give [emacsthemes](https://emacsthemes.com/) a try, especially the *github* one.

It is available via [melpa](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/getting-started) (don't miss their getting started if you are new to package management with emacs) ; the version seems pretty maintained - last version here : 20170413.

Don't forget to `M-x customize-themes` once installed to activate it.

Comment: Sadly, there are 2 github themes and both are different to what Github actually uses:  ![Compare](https://imfilesscreens.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub-Theme-for-Emacsgithub-theme.el_at_master__philiparvidssonGitHub-Theme-for-Emacs_2017-06-15_10-02-38.png).

Comment: I decided I will just an [issue](https://github.com/philiparvidsson/GitHub-Theme-for-Emacs/issues/13) in the themes repository. This should solve it for me, thanks!